# Jquery save edited value on array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, key-value

I have a table with detail in it. The user is able to edit the details. I have an array to populate the table, what  I want to do is to be able to save the edited value in the same array pairing the key to it's value.

Example: My array looks like this:

```
var employee= [
{NAME:"John",
SURNAME:"Smith",
ADDRESS:"2579 Perry Street"
}]
```

User want to change the address of the employee. User click button "Save" to save the edited address, on the click of the button I save all the edited information on the array with key:value.So now my array should look like this:

```
var employee= [
{NAME:"John",
SURNAME:"Smith",
ADDRESS:"25 May Street"
}]
```

For now I can save the edited items, but it doesn't pair it with the key, it just save it like this:

```
var employee= [
{NAME:"John",
SURNAME:"Smith",
ADDRESS:"2579 Perry Street"
},"John","Smith","25 May Street"
]
```

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //ricerca dipendente
  $("#filter_employee").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var surname = $('#surname').val();

    $("#employee_search").show();
    filter_employee(name, surname);
  })


}); //DOM

function filter_employee(name, surname) {

  var filters = [];
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var surname = $('#surname').val();

  if (name) {
    filters.push({
      field: "NAME",
      operator: "contains",
      value: name
    });
  }
  if (surname) {
    filters.push({
      field: "SURNAME",
      operator: "contains",
      value: surname
    });
  }

  $("#employee_search").kendoGrid({
    title: "Search Result",
    dataSource: {
      data: employee,
      filter: {
        logic: "and",
        filters: filters,
      },
    },
    height: 450,
    selectable: true,
    detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template_employee").html()),
    detailInit: detailInit,
    detailExpand: function(e) {
      e.sender.tbody.find('.k-detail-row').each(function(idx, item) {
        if (item !== e.detailRow[0]) {
          e.sender.collapseRow($(item).prev());
        }
      })
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "NAME",
        title: "Name",
        width: 240
      }, {
        field: "SURNAME",
        title: "Surname"
      },
      {
        command: [{
          name: "destroy",
          click: function(e) {
            var row = $(this);
            var tr = row.closest('tr');
            var model = grid.dataItem(tr);
            model.hide();
          }
        }, ]
      }
    ],
  });


  function detailInit(e) {
    var detailRow = e.detailRow;

    detailRow.find(".detailTabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
      animation: {
        open: {
          effects: "fadeIn"
        }
      }
    });

  }
}

function saveEdits() {

  $('#personal').find(':input').each(function() {
    employee.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(employee)
  //get the editable element
  var editElem = $("#personal k-textbox");
  //get the edited element content
  var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
  //save the content to local storage
  sessionStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

  console.log("Edits saved!");
  $("#save_edit_data").hide();
  $("#cancel_edit_data").hide();
  $('#personal input').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

}


var employee = [{
    NAME: "John",
    SURNAME: "Smith",
    ADDRESS: "2579 Perry Street, Westland, MI 48185",
    TEL: "810-602-5231",
    ID: "M05",
    ID_C_SITE: "564NSD"
  },
  {
    NAME: "Kimberly",
    SURNAME: "C. Kelly",
    ADDRESS: "2579 Perry Street, Westland, MI 48185",
    TEL: "810-602-5231",
    ID: "M05",
    ID_C_SITE: "564NSD"
  }
]
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="k-content">
  <div id="dipendenti">
    <h1 class="title">Employee Detail</h1>
    <div class="searchbar">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" class="k-textbox">
      <label for="surname">Surname</label>
      <input id="surname" name="surname" class="k-textbox">

      <button class="k-button" id="filter_employee">Search</button>

    </div>
    <div id="employee_search" class="hide"></div>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template_employee">
      <div class="detailTabstrip">
        <ul>
          <li class="k-state-active">Personal Data</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <span class="personal">&nbsp;</span>
          <div id="personal" class="detail_table" contenteditable="false">
            <div>
              <li><label>Codice ID: </label><input class="k-textbox" value=#=ID #></li>
            </div>
            <div>
              <li><label>Name: </label><input class="k-textbox" value=#=NAME #></li>
            </div>
            <div>
              <li><label>Surname: </label><input class="k-textbox" value=#=SURNAME #></li>
            </div>
            <div>
              <li><label>Address: </label><input class="k-textbox" value=#=ADDRESS #></li>
            </div>
            <div>
              <li><label>ID Construction Site: </label><input class="k-textbox" value=#=ID_C_SITE #></li>
            </div>
            <div>
              <li><label>Telephone: </label><input class="k-textbox" value=#=TEL #></li>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button id="save_edit_data" value="save" onclick="saveEdits()" / class="k-button save">Save</button>
            <button id="cancel_edit_data" class="k-button cancel" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change it to be a [mcve]

Comment: `employee.push($(this).val());` That's pushing the strings to the array. If you want it to find the correct object, you need to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) it and set the values appropriately. You're unlikely to be able to just loop through the inputs.